# How to align the menu to center after certain width media query fires for RWD

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to align the menu to center after certain width  media query for  mobile RWD and how to make the width of 3 buttons same & show down under each button ?

Here is the html markup:

```
<div class="m">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AboutUs</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contactus</a></li>
</ul
</div>
<button>submit</button>
<button>b1</button>
<button>apply result</button>
```

link with html & CSS with working code :
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/jimoscarlobo/gsomLzjv/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center align a list menu like this:

- Set `text-align: center` on its parent
- Set `display: inline-block; text-align: left;` on the list menu
- Set `display: block;` on menu items and the links within

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/gsomLzjv/1/), [**Full screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/gsomLzjv/1/show/)